# Change Div's positions based on id dynamically with css / jquery

Tags: jquery

Using CSS Sectors and JQuery, I want to reposition the div based on the id passed by the user. Let us say user passes 1683 in the query string, i want the div with id post-1683 on the top and then follows post-1681, post-1682, post-1684

Here is the **current format**.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">....</div>
    <div class="post-1681 status-publish hentry id="post-1681">.......</div>
    <div class="post-1682 status-publish hentry id="post-1682">.......</div>
    **<div class="post-1683 status-publish hentry id="post-1683">.......</div>**
    <div class="post-1684 status-publish hentry id="post-1684">.......</div>
</div>
```

but the **expected display** should be the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">....</div>
    **<div class="post-1683 status-publish hentry id="post-1683">.......</div>**
    <div class="post-1681 status-publish hentry id="post-1681">.......</div>
    <div class="post-1682 status-publish hentry id="post-1682">.......</div>
    <div class="post-1684 status-publish hentry id="post-1684">.......</div>
</div>
```

Please keep in mind all these div id's are dynamically generated but the div which i want to display on the top will be available to me through Query param.

Comment: So the user passes an ID in the URL, then you ostensibly generate the HTML from jQuery or a DB call, and then the container is updated. Is that correct? How are you doing this now? What jQuery have you tried?

Comment: How are you adding it now?

Comment: What do you mean by adding, I am not adding anything at this time and if you see i get all the rows and display in a sequential manner, What i want is change the positioning of the div's

Comment: OK so your have the full list already in the page and you just want to re-order based on the URL parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var id="1683";
$('#post-'+id).insertAfter($('div.head'));
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/B45NQ/)**

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to add your new element after `div` with class `head`. Is that so?

Then you can use `after()` like this:

```
$(".head").after('<div class="post-1683 status-publish hentry id="post-1683">...</div>');
```

Or, if you already have all `div`s and then want to re-position it then you would need to detach it first and do this:

```
$(".post-1683").detach().insertAfter(".head");
```

Working code:
http://jsbin.com/rodotovo/1/edit

Comment: any specific reason for .detach, it works nicely without that as well.

Comment: No, not any reason but comes from exactly what needs to be done in real scenarios so answered what first came into mind :)